# SUM a column then SUBTRACT the SUM of another column and get values 0 instead of negative values

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join, laravel-8

how can I get `$sum` 0 values instead of negative values? I've seen that people use `< then .. else 0` but when I try, it display the wrong value :(

stock_movement_details.db:-
[image]

stock_movement.db
[image]

raw_material.db
[image]

As you can see, I have type (subtract/add). Let say, ID 10 for raw_material_id, quantity is 10.00, ID 11&12 subtract 9.48, logic is (10- 9.48 -9.48 = -8.96). However, instead of getting negative values, I want it to be 0.

Table that display quantity balance:-
[image]

```
$rawMaterials = RawMaterials::where(['status' => 'Active'])->get();

$rawMaterials = $rawMaterials->map(function ($f) {

$total = DB::select('select 
         ( sum(case when detail.type="add" then detail.quantity else 0 end) - sum(case when detail.type="subtract" then detail.quantity else 0 end) ) as total
         from stock_movement_details detail
         left join stock_movements main on main.id = detail.stock_movement_id
         where detail.raw_material_id = ?
         ', [$f->id]);

            $sum = 0;
            foreach ($total as $t) {
                $sum += $t->total;
            }

            $rawMats = [
                "id" => $f->id,
                "total" => $sum,
            ];
            return $rawMats;
        });
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please provide us with sample data, actual and expected results, ideally as a db fiddle. As it stands, we can't help you - it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @NevilleKuyt, thank youuu. I've edited the question, please take a look and I hope it will help :"

Comment: That's better - it would be _even_ better if you didn't use pictures, but formatted text, and perfect if you used db-fiddle.com.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really know about it ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another `CASE` expression in your query, to check if `total` is negative, but this would mean that you should repeat the expression that calculates the difference of the 2 sums.

It's better to use your query as a subquery and check `total` in the outer query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN total < 0 THEN 0 ELSE total END AS total
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN d.type = "add" THEN d.quantity ELSE 0 END) - 
         SUM(CASE WHEN d.type = "subtract" THEN d.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS total
  FROM stock_movement_details d LEFT JOIN stock_movements m 
  ON m.id = d.stock_movement_id
  WHERE d.raw_material_id = ?
) t
```

Also, I don't see the need for a `LEFT` join of  `stock_movement_details` to `stock_movements` because you are not using any columns of `stock_movements` in your query.

You can simplify to:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN total < 0 THEN 0 ELSE total END AS total
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = "add" THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) - 
         SUM(CASE WHEN type = "subtract" THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS total
  FROM stock_movement_details
  WHERE raw_material_id = ?
) t
```

Or:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN total < 0 THEN 0 ELSE total END AS total
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(CASE type WHEN "add" THEN 1 WHEN "subtract" THEN -1 ELSE 0 END * quantity) AS total
  FROM stock_movement_details
  WHERE raw_material_id = ?
) t
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the `t` at the ending is for?

Comment: @cdogol in MySql all subqueries must have an alias so `t` is the alias of the subquery.

Comment: I need to LEFT JOIN it because in the stock_movement_details.db, got the stock_movement_id which came from stock_movements.db. By the way, your code works! Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it! I'm going to try to understand it first instead of copy and paste. Thank you so much!! T-T